# How to use -not in find?

Tags: linux, bash

Let's say I have a directory structure like so

```
mkdir -p test/1
mkdir -p test/2
mkdir -p test/3
touch test/1/touch
touch test/2/touch
touch test/3/touch
```

How do I find all files in `test/` except those in `test/2`?

Comment: may be a better fit for Serverfault or Unix&Linux.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Another **short** find variant to get this done is:

```
find test ! -path "test/2*"
```

**OUTPUT**

```
test
test/1
test/1/touch
test/3
test/3/touch
```

Answer (score 3):

Use `-prune`:

```
find test -path 'test/2' -prune -or -print
```

Comment: That works for me, but can you explain a bit? I personally have trouble with `find` and why stuff like that (`-or -print`) works sometimes...

Comment: @DanFego: I'm afraid I can't write a better explanation than the one given at the `-prune` example in the `find` manpage.

Comment: Ohhhhhhh it just hit me. If the path is `'test/2'`, then it's `true && true || print`, in which case `print` doesn't happen? Otherwise it's `false && true || print`, in which case it does.

Comment: @DanFego: Exactly. This is just the explanation in the manpage :-). Additionally, though, `-prune` has the explicit side-effect of *not* recursing into the subpath. So the `-o` is for the directory itself, the `-prune` for its subdirectories.

Answer (score 1):

There's some [good examples here](http://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/linux-unix-osx-bsd-find-command-exclude-directories/) for directory exclusion when searching.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `-not` this way:

```
find -not -wholename './test/2*'
```

Comment: @DanFego: Yes. If there are more than 9 subdirectories, they should be named 01, 02... :-)

Comment: touche! Though then someone will find this and start a question about how to rename all their directories. :P